# Enforce Foreign Key with Pydantic for a SqlAlchemy model

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, pydantic

I have two models, one called measurement, one called device. Each device can send measurements to the API as long as they are registered in the device model. There is a foreign key relationship, and SQLAlchemy will throw an error if you try to insert a measurement for a device that is not registered. However, I would like to know how to make my Pydantic schema catch this before SQLAlchemy throws an error. Below is my schema and models.py (this is for fastapi).

schemas.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class DeviceBase(BaseModel):
    name: str
    hardware: str
    firmware: str
    software: str


class DeviceCreate(DeviceBase):
    id: int
    device_key: str


class Device(DeviceBase):
    id: int
    device_key: str


class DeviceRelate(BaseModel):
    device_key: str


class MeasurementBase(BaseModel):
    inside_temp: float
    outside_temp: float
    inside_humidty: float
    outside_humidity: float
    current_capacity: float
    device_key: DeviceRelate

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class MeasurementCreate(MeasurementBase):
    pass


class Measurement(MeasurementBase):
    id: int
    device_key: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Float, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .database import Base
import datetime


class Measurement(Base):
    __tablename__ = "measurements"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    device_key = Column(String(length=40), ForeignKey("devices.device_key"))
    inside_temp = Column(Float)
    outside_temp = Column(Float)
    inside_humidity = Column(Float)
    outside_humidity = Column(Float)
    current_capacity = Column(Float)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone('America/Los_Angeles')))

    device = relationship("Device", back_populates="measurements")


class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = "devices"
    device_key = Column(String(length=40), unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    hardware = Column(String)
    firmware = Column(String)
    software = Column(String)

    measurements = relationship("Measurement", back_populates="device")
```

Side note also, what effect does the orm_mode = True have?

Edit: After adding the supplied answer, it makes sense to me, but I get an error that reads "sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sql_app.schemas.MeasurementCreate' is not mapped". My guess is something is out of scope maybe? I've included the main.py file as well so you can see my routes

```
class MeasurementBase(BaseModel):
    inside_temp: float
    outside_temp: float
    inside_humidty: float
    outside_humidity: float
    current_capacity: float

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    @staticmethod
    def device_key_validator(value: str, session: Session):
        if not session.query(models.Device).filter_by(device_key=value).first():
            raise ValueError("Device with specified device key does not exist")


class MeasurementCreate(MeasurementBase):
    device_key: str = Field(validators=[MeasurementBase.device_key_validator])


class Measurement(MeasurementBase):
    id: int
    device_key: DeviceBase

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sql_app.database import engine, Session
from sql_app import models
import sql_app.schemas as schemas
from sql_app.database import Base, get_db


def create_tables():
    print("Creating Tables..")
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/measurement/")
async def create_measurement(measurement: schemas.MeasurementCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    new_measurement = schemas.MeasurementCreate(**measurement.dict(), session=Session)
    db.add(new_measurement)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_measurement)
    return measurement


@app.post("/create_device/")
async def create_device(device: schemas.DeviceCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    new_device = models.Device(device_key=device.device_key,
                               name=device.name,
                               hardware=device.hardware,
                               firmware=device.firmware,
                               software=device.software
                               )
    db.add(new_device)
    db.commit()
    return db.refresh(new_device)
```

Comment: Generally validation of external references probably isn't a good thing to try to shoehorn into your Pydantic model; let the service layer handle it for you (i.e. `device_service.add_new_device(device)`) and let that apply any rules for what is a valid reference (which can be further limited by users, groups, etc. in your application). This doesn't fit well with how Pydantic is used in FastAPI by default (and will often be a business rule and not a data validation rule). The `orm_mode` setting allows Pydantic to populate any object through attributes as well as keys (`.foo` vs `['foo']`).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `level-1` and `level-2` validations.

### level-1 - pydantic validation

- Basic data validation like min, max, string length, etc

### level-2 - service validation

- Get pydantic validated data
- Apply database/api services validations
- example: foreign key constraints, third party service data validations, etc.

After you validate data at level 1 and level 2 then you can play with the validated data [i.e store it into DB] and return the response.

Comment: Do you have docs to this?

Comment: no, you can check https://youtu.be/K7rlHEnF2-M